# How to stop Microsoft Edge opening Bing links in a new tab

Tags: tabs, microsoft-edge, bing

When I click on a Bing search results link in Microsoft Edge the linked page opens in a new tab. How do I change the default behaviour so that the linked page opens in the same tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open https://www.bing.com/account/general#settings_results in Microsoft Edge, and you will have to disable the "Open links from search results in a new tab or window" from the 'Results' section. And click '**Save**'.